# c# MetroTextBox Keydown Enter Key triggering

Tags: c#

Enter Key is not working in Metro Textbox. please help me

```
private void metroTextBox3_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
  { 
     textBox1.Focus(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: WPF or Winforms?

Comment: In Windows form MetroTextBox enter key not responding in keydown event

Comment: The function is set in the properties of the `metroTextBox3`? Is the `metroTextBox3` selected when the key press is performed?

Comment: metrotextbox is Textbox. when i am using other key instead of "ENTER" key its working. But when i use "Keys.Enter" its not working

Comment: KINDLY HELP PLEASE

Comment: if other keys are working I am confused why this is not working. Can you debug your Code and see whats the KeyCode of e?

Comment: I actually installed Metro Framework. So in normal textbox enter key works perfect when inuse Metro TextBox then enter key is not working. So thats why i am asking..it may include some other coding. Cause MetroFramwork doesn't recognize Enter key in TextBox

Comment: Sorry for the late response.... have you tried other events like KeyDown()?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you kan use `Control.KeyDown` event. This event occurs when a key is pressed while the control has focus.

[Control.KeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Your code will look like:

```
private void metroTextBox3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyDownEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
  { 
     textBox1.Focus(); 
  }
}
```

If you press `Enter` for example, the runtime value of `e.KeyValue` will be 13.

[image: Runtime]